# ¿Cómo encontrar un archivo concreto en todo el sistema?

Tags: python, python-3.x

He intentado realizar lo siguiente:

```
def get_file_location(name, path):
    for dirpath,dirname,filename in os.walk(path):
        if name in filename:
            return os.path.join(dirpath,name)

filepath = get_file_location("Login Data","/")
print(filepath)
```

De esta forma he podido encontrar un archivo con el nombre "Login Data" en la siguiente ruta:

> /Users\Oscar\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data

En este archivo Google almacena las credenciales de acceso a los sitios que has accedido previamente desde Chrome. De la misma forma, Microsoft almacena en un archivo del mismo nombre que el anterior mencionado pero en la carpeta de Edge y necesito que no interfiera nunca con el archivo de Chrome a la hora de buscar la ruta del archivo.

Si intento ser más explícito al seleccionar la ruta, el código modificado es el siguiente:

```
filepath = get_file_location("Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data","/")
```

El error es el siguiente:

> File "C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\Projects\Proyecto
> del navegador Chrome\main.py", line 8
> filepath = get_file_location("Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data","/")
> ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode
> bytes in position 6-7: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape [Finished in 3.2s]

Answer (score 2):

Como tu cadena `Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data` tiene una secuencia de escape que comienza con `\U`, Python está tratando de decodificarla como una secuencia de escape Unicode de 8 caracteres

Utiliza doble diagonal invertida `\\` en lugar de una sola `\`:

```
filepath = get_file_location("Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data","/")
```

Utiliza una cadena de texto sin formato, también conocida como raw string, para evitar que Python interprete las secuencias de escape:

```
filepath = get_file_location(r"Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data","/")
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.